# why is my check50 in cs50p (PROBLEM SET 5: ) is not working for the test_bank problem as my code is not exiting with 0

Tags: python, testing, cs50

I am doing the cs50p course and am on problem set 5, on the second problem,  but when I execute my code check50 says it is not exiting with code0 when I execute it myself it does however execute with code0, My code is objective is to test another function.

in this code the function I am trying to test is the value function:

```
def main():
    x = input("Greeting: ")
    print(value(x))

def value(greeting):
    greeting = greeting.lower().strip()
    if greeting.startswith("hello"):
        return "$0"
    elif greeting.startswith("h"):
        return "$20"
    else:
        return "$100"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the code I am using to test the value function:

```
from bank import value

def test_hello():
    assert value("hello") == "$0"
    assert value("HELLO, mark") == "$0"

def test_h_words():
    assert value("hi") == "$20"
    assert value("howdy") == "$20"

def test_other_words():
    assert value("money") == "$100"
    assert value("food") == "$100"

def test_h_in_middle():
    assert value("she") == "$100"

def test_numbers():
    assert value("123") == "$100"

def test_symbols():
    assert value("!@#$%^&*") == "$100"
```

[image: this is the check50 error I am getting]

Comment: The code you claim test the `value` function, that doesn't test anything at all. You just define some functions, but you never call them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: if OP is using `pytest`, it automatically discovers functions starting with `test_` in modules starting with `test_`. So it may well be running those tests.

Comment: To the OP: For future question, tell us how you run the tests you created. If you use `pytest` then say so.

Answer (score 1):

The [specifications](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/5/test_bank/) for your problem state that your function should (paraphrased):

> return 0 if the input string starts with "hello", 20 if it starts with an “h” but is not “hello”, or 100 otherwise, treating the string case-insensitively.

Your function is *not* returning those values, it is instead returning a string representation of them.

Hence your first test case should be something like:

```py
def test_hello():
    assert value("hello") == 0
    assert value("HELLO, mark") == 0
```

When you fix that and the other test cases, you'll find that your code as written starts failing the tests. It should hopefully be fairly easy for you to fix the code at that point, given you've already figured out how to create matching text and target code.